# Limit Windows XP machine's bandwidth between 9AM - 11PM

Tags: bandwidth, bandwidth-control

Hay, i need to find a software solution to a problem. I want to be able to limit a Windows XP machine's bandwidth on all ports between 10AM - 11PM.

I have access to the machine in question, i need an application which can achieve this. I want to be able to limit to bandwidth to something like 10kb/s between these times.

Any solutions?

Comment: Can you run this machine in a VM?

Comment: What is your desired behavior when the limit is reached?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/) can probably do the job.

Answer (score 1):

I was curious myself if Windows has an "in-house" way of doing this.  Apparently, [a part of SCCM, called Data Protection Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc161325.aspx) **partly** offers what you are looking for, if I understand it correctly.  That requires you have much more enterprise infrastructure than just a Windows XP box, so I cannot be certain that is even an option.

More in your ballpark, but still requires some infrastructure, is modifying a Group Policy, if you have an Active Directory Domain, is modifying Group Policy settings under **Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Network -> QoS Packet Scheduler -> Limit reservable bandwidth**.  As the policy setting description states:

> At least Windows XP Professional or
>   Windows Server 2003 family
>
> Determines the percentage of
>   connection bandwidth that the system
>   can reserve. This value limits the
>   combined bandwidth reservations of all
>   programs running on the system.
>
> By default, the Packet Scheduler
>   limits the system to 20 percent of the
>   bandwidth of a connection, but you can
>   use this setting to override the
>   default.
>
> If you enable this setting, you can
>   use the "Bandwidth limit" box to
>   adjust the amount of bandwidth the
>   system can reserve.
>
> If you disable this setting or do not
>   configure it, the system uses the
>   default value of 20 percent of the
>   connection.
>
> Important: If a bandwidth limit is set
>   for a particular network adapter in
>   the registry, this setting is ignored
>   when configuring that network adapter.

This also requires you get intimately acquanited with WMI filters in said GPO's for your time requirement, but I am not sure they are that reliable (in terms of on the dime processing at a given time, since refresh rates, IMHO, are quite variable in larger, poorly-maintained domains common to big companies like I deal with).

That being said, these are bizarre solutions.  I modded up the NetLimiter answer, but is anyone doing anything like this in a big enterprise environment?  Would love to hear stories if it works well.